# apps script copy input sheet row cell data to output sheet as transposed column data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to copy data from input sheet to output sheet transposed. First time to copy between sheets, not very experienced. I have tried many methods to do the copyTo line of code looking at previous similar stackoverflow reports.
Error "Missing ; before statement. (line 11, file "Code")
Line 11 is last line, the inRng.copyTo ...

```
function fetchData() {
  //Browser.msgBox("Test Button");
  var inData = ("FUNGRAPH9");
  var outData = ("Data");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var input = ss.getSheetByName(inData);
  var output = ss.getSheetByName(outData);
  //test getting data for 1st chart
  inRng = input.getRange(10,3,1,7); 
  outRng = output.getRange(6,21,12,21); 
  inRng.copyTo(outData,6,21,12,21).CopyPasteType.transposed);
}
```

Revised code as Tanaike answered. It works now. thanks!

```
  function fetchData() {
  //Browser.msgBox("Test Button");
  var inData = ("FUNGRAPH9");
  var outData = ("Data");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var input = ss.getSheetByName(inData);
  var output = ss.getSheetByName(outData);
  //test getting data for 1st chart
  inRng = input.getRange(10,3,1,7);
  outRng = output.getRange("U6");
  inRng.copyTo(outRng, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, true);
}
```

Comment: When you want to copy the value of "C10:I10" to the cells "U6:AO17" by transposing the value. If my understanding is correct, for example, how about modifying the last line to ``inRng.copyTo(outRng, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, true)``? [Document of ``copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)``](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-copypastetype-transposed) I posted as a comment, because I'm not sure whether this is the result you want.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, I'm trying to transpose to cells  U6:U12  (row,col,rowEnd,colEnd). Are fields actually (row,col,numRow,numCol)? I's also confused on documentation for how to specify the copyPasteType parameters to transpose on output sheet.

Comment: Thanks again Tanaike . I implemented your suggestion and it worked perfectly. Code is now:

Comment: function fetchData() {
  //Browser.msgBox("Test Button");
  var inData = ("FUNGRAPH9");
  var outData = ("Data");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var input = ss.getSheetByName(inData);
  var output = ss.getSheetByName(outData);
  //test getting data for 1st chart
  inRng = input.getRange(10,3,1,7);
  outRng = output.getRange("U6");
  inRng.copyTo(outRng, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, true);
}

Comment: Tanaike - Sorry for the garbled code. Still learning how to use this system.

Comment: Think I have it readable now!

Comment: I'm glad your issue was resolved. Can you post the solution as an answer and accept it? By this, other users can see your question as the resolved it.

Comment: Tanaike - This was my first question on stackoverflow and I've been trying to find exactly how to post the solution as an answer and accept it. Hate to take more of your time, but if you could point me in the right direction. Doesn't look like it is 'Answer Your Question' or one of the icons on top left.

Answer (score 0):

I used Tanaike's answer (modified for my corrected case) and it worked, Corrected code:

```
  function fetchData() {
  //Browser.msgBox("Test Button");
  var inData = ("FUNGRAPH9");
  var outData = ("Data");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var input = ss.getSheetByName(inData);
  var output = ss.getSheetByName(outData);
  //test getting data for 1st chart
  inRng = input.getRange(10,3,1,7);
  outRng = output.getRange("U6");
  inRng.copyTo(outRng, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, true);
}
```